# How to make a field default in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app am trying to make a location based search from scratch, i have three fields for location State, City, Area. Where State has many cities, cities belongs to a state, cities have many areas and area belongs to a city.

it works totally fine for me right now user can select state, city and area and can complete the search but what i want is if a user is logged in and select a state, city and area, it should get saved in his account as default location, so that even if he logs out and logs in again he should not have to add his state, city and area again.

**Here is my code**

```
<form class="form-wrap mt-4">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
    <input type="text" placeholder="What are your looking for?" id="search" class="btn-group1">

    <div class="select-wapper">
      <%= select_tag :state, options_for_select([["Select a state",""]] + State.all.map { |c| [c.name, c.id] } ), id: "state"%>
    </div>
    <div class="select-wapper">
      <%= select_tag :city, options_for_select([["Select a City",""]]), :id => 'city' %>
    </div>
    <div class="select-wapper">
      <%= select_tag :area, options_for_select([["Select a Area",""]]), :id => 'area' %>
    </div>
    <a href="/welcome/search" class="btn-form search-btn">SEARCH<i class="pe-7s-angle-right"></i></a>
  </div>
</form>
```

**My welcome_controller** (before applying @cnnr's answer)

```
  def search
  @products = Product.where('(name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? )', "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%")
  @products = @products.where(state: params[:state]) if params[:state].present?
  @products = @products.where(city: params[:city]) if params[:city].present?
  end
```

**My welcome_controller** (After applying @cnnr's answer.)

```
  def search
  @products = Product.where('(name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? )', "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%")
  @products = @products.where(state: params[:state]) if params[:state].present?
  @products = @products.where(city: params[:city]) if params[:city].present?


  search_results = handle_search_params(params[:search])

    current_user.update_attributes(
      search_state: params[:search][:state],
      search_city: params[:search][:city],
      search_area: params[:search][:area]
    )

    respond_with(search_results) 
  end
end
```

**After applying @cnnr answer am getting this error while searching**

```
undefined method `handle_search_params' for #<WelcomeController:0x00007f5a752e1950>
```

I hope it is enough info. Am really new to rails , i have searched a lot but didn't got any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may save user's search params in your `users` table.
For example, first, add search fields to `User` model:

```
class AddSearchFieldsForUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :users, :search_state, :text
    add_column :users, :search_city, :text 
    add_column :users, :search_area, :text
  end
end
```

Then run

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

After that update `WelcomeController`

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  # `current_user` below is your authorized user
  # I assume, that you're using [devise][1] gem
  # because `current_user` helper belongs to it
  # If you're getting user instance otherwise
  # you should use your solution
  def search
    # I've just copy-paste your code with database querying
    # It should be optimized with scopes at model level,
    # but this is not the main question
    @products = Product.where('(name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? )', "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%")
    @products = @products.where(state: params[:state]) if params[:state].present?
    @products = @products.where(city: params[:city]) if params[:city].present?

    if current_user
      current_user.update_attributes(
        search_state: params[:state],
        search_city: params[:city],
        search_area: params[:area]
      )
    end

    respond_with @products
  end

  ...
end
```

And in your search form (I've strip wrappers for shortness):

```
<form class="form-wrap mt-4">
    ...
    <input type="text" placeholder="What are your looking for?" id="search" class="btn-group1">
    <%= select_tag :state,
        options_for_select([["Select a state",""]] + State.all.map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }, current_user.search_state ), id: "state"%>
    <%= select_tag :city,
        options_for_select([["Select a City",""]], current_user.search_city), :id => 'city' %>
    <%= select_tag :area,
        options_for_select([["Select a Area",""]], current_user.search_area), :id => 'area' %>
    ...
</form>
```

It's very simple explanation, and I'm ready to update my answer if you'll need more details.

Link to [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) (it's not parsed at code block)

Comment: hi @cnnr thanks for your answer, i think your answer was spot on, but it doesn't worked, i have updated my question with the error and my controller, please have a look it will be a great help. Thanks again.